# How can I make yarp match path case insensitive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reverse-proxy, ms-yarp

My route is

```
"Routes": [
{
    "RouteId": "routegreen",
    "ClusterId": "clustergreen",
    "Match": {
        "Path": "/api/myendpoint"
    }
}
```

It is not matched for requests going to `/api/MyEndpoint`. Is it possible to make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. These are not Windows filenames - URL's included in routing are always case sensitive. You have no choice but to rename, either in the routing addresses, or your method name, to match case exactly.

Comment: I totally get it that an url should be case sensitive but the configuration might have an option for case insensitiv matching. I actually find something in the source of yarp (matcher.IsCaseSensitive) , just need to find the correct syntax for it

Comment: I dont think it exists. In .NET ASP there is (was) case-insensitive routing, but for Core they already changed that. Don't know about yarp actually, but it simply should not be there. Routing is case-sensitive. You'll have to set up a separate routing case for MyEndpoint explicitly.

Comment: I guess you are right matcher.IsCaseSensitive was actually for matching header values